# Convert this table to latex

Tags: tables

May anybody helps me how to convert the attached image (table) to latex format?

I don't know how to do that.

[image]

Comment: @Mohammad Welcome! Can you please post the code you've got for the table so far, preferably in the form of minimal code we can compile. Start with `\documentclass{article}` and end with `\end{document}`. Even just providing the textual content for the table would be a big help to the people trying to help you. I don't think your question should be closed this quickly, but it does need some improvement or it is at risk of being closed.

Comment: Also, please post comments in English if you possibly can. Most users won't understand otherwise.

Comment: @cfr thank you for your welcome. I'm a bit new to LaTex. :)

Comment: @Mohammad We were all there once. Don't feel you need to leave. It is very common for people not to have much idea how to help people who are trying to help them. People often have no idea how this site works or what to put in a question. (Or what to put in an answer.) I started off by posting in completely the wrong place very early on - at least you put your question in the right box!

Comment: @cfr - I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: There's a web tool that can help you do all that quite easily: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As shown, this is a relatively complex table to format well since it requires the following elements:

- rotated cells -> `rotating` package
- cells which span multiple columns -> `\multicolumn{<number of columns>}{<alignment>}{<content>}`
- cells which span multiple rows -> `multirow` package

In addition, LaTeX tables do not, by default allow sufficient vertical spacing. This problem is exacerbated by the use of horizontal rules. Moreover, some horizontal rules should typically be heavier than others. To accommodate these considerations in a table with vertical rules, I used `makecell`. I also used `array` which is a basic extension of the standard LaTeX syntax and makes it a bit easier to customise things.

So, in the document preamble, we have

```
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,makecell,array}
```

to load the packages. I used 3 different rule weights: standard, a bit thicker and thicker still. For convenience, we define the non-standard rule heights in one place so they can be easily modified and consistently applied.

```
\newlength\xlineht
\newlength\mlineht
\setlength\xlineht{1.2pt}
\setlength\mlineht{.8pt}
```

We define a couple of extra column types for convenience and consistency again.

```
\newcolumntype{C}{c!{\vrule width \xlineht}}
\newcolumntype{M}{c!{\vrule width \mlineht}}
```

`makecell` allows us to configure some extra spacing around cells, which we need. So we set some things up.

```
\setcellgapes{3pt}
```

We want our headers to be bold.

```
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
```

That's it for the preamble. Now, in the document itself.

```
\begin{table}
```

Put the table in the `table` environment if you want it to float. If you do this, you probably want to use a `\caption{}` and `\label{}` so you can refer to it in the text.

If you don't want the table to move from where you put it, use the `center` environment instead.

```
  \makegapedcells
```

This applies our extra spacing around cells.

```
  \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}c|M*{3}{c|}C}
```

Here's the `tabular` specification: start at the left with a vertical rule of width thicker-still; then a centred column and a standard rule; then one of our custom columns, `M`; then 3 centred columns followed by standard rules; finally another custom column, `C`.

```
    \Xhline{\xlineht}
```

A rule of height thicker-still to start.

```
    \multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}M}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{C1}} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{\thead{C2}}\\\cline{3-6}
```

The first header row, using `\multicolumn` for cells spanning 2 columns and `\thead` for header content, followed by a partial rule.

```
    \multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}M}{}& \thead{P1} & \thead{P2} & \thead{P1} & \thead{P2} \\\cline{3-6}
```

The second header row.

```
    \multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}M}{}& {0.33} & {0.66} & {0.2} & {0.8} \\\Xhline{\mlineht}
```

The third header row with cell contents not formatted as headers, followed by a thicker rule.

Now for the first cell spanning multiple rows (9), which is also rotated. We use `\rotatebox` rather than `makecell` here because I couldn't figure out how to do this with `makecell`'s own rotation wrappers.

```
    \multirowcell{9}{\rotatebox[]{-90}{\theadfont Different alpha}} & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{25} \\\cline{2-6}
```

And some more column-spanning content and a partial rule.

We continue in the same way.

```
    & 0.2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{67} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.3 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{890} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.4 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{34} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.5 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{23} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.6 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{25} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.7 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{69} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{54} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.8 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{21} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.9 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{69} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{55} \\\hline
```

Here comes the second rotated cell spanning multiple columns.

```
    \multirowcell{9}{\rotatebox[]{-90}{\theadfont Different beta}} & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{19} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{69} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{83} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.3 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{35} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.4 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{64} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.5 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{46} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.6 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{12} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.7 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{16} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.8 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{71} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.9 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{38} \\\Xhline{\xlineht}
```

We end with a thicker-still rule.

```
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: fancy table]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,makecell,array}
\newlength\xlineht
\newlength\mlineht
\setlength\xlineht{1.2pt}
\setlength\mlineht{.8pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{c!{\vrule width \xlineht}}
\newcolumntype{M}{c!{\vrule width \mlineht}}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}c|M*{3}{c|}C}
    \Xhline{\xlineht}
    \multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}M}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{C1}} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{\thead{C2}}\\\cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}M}{}& \thead{P1} & \thead{P2} & \thead{P1} & \thead{P2} \\\cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width \xlineht}M}{}& {0.33} & {0.66} & {0.2} & {0.8} \\\Xhline{\mlineht}
    \multirowcell{9}{\rotatebox[]{-90}{\theadfont Different alpha}} & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{25} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{67} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.3 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{890} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.4 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{34} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.5 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{23} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.6 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{25} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.7 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{69} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{54} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.8 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{21} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.9 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{69} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{55} \\\hline
    \multirowcell{9}{\rotatebox[]{-90}{\theadfont Different beta}} & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{19} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{69} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{83} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.3 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{35} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.4 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{64} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.5 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{46} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.6 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{12} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.7 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{16} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.8 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{71} \\\cline{2-6}
    & 0.9 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{38} \\\Xhline{\xlineht}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note, however, that professional-quality tables do not typically use vertical rules at all and use horizontal rules much more sparingly. For an informed, if possibly slightly extreme, discussion, see the manual of the `booktabs` package.

For example, I would probably use something like this.

[image: less is more]

This overdoes the rules a little by the standards of `booktabs`, but is much simpler and clearer than the original. As a bonus, the code is much, much simpler! Less really is more where tables are concerned and less is fortunately easier by far to typeset.

In this case, we load `booktabs` instead of `makecell,array` and we roll our own header font command with

```
\newcommand*\myheadfont{\bfseries}
```

Dropping the vertical rules means that the `tabular` specifier is just `*{6}{c}` for 6 centred columns.

Using `booktabs` gives us

- `\toprule` for the rule at the top;
- `\bottomrule` for the rule at the bottom;
- `\midrule` for rules in the middle;
- `\cmidrule(){}` for partial rules in the middle.

In particular, we can 'trim` partial rules to the left and/or right to create a gap between consecutive rules in the header.

[image: gap]

We aren't using `makecell` now, so we use `\multirow` for the cells spanning multiple columns, with `*` specifying the natural width.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,booktabs}
\newcommand*\myheadfont{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
    \toprule
    && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\myheadfont C1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\myheadfont C2}\\\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    && \myheadfont P1 & \myheadfont P2 & \myheadfont P1 & \myheadfont P2 \\
    && {0.33} & {0.66} & {0.2} & {0.8} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{9}*{\rotatebox[]{-90}{\myheadfont Different alpha}} & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{25} \\
    & 0.2 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{67} \\
    & 0.3 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{890} \\
    & 0.4 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{34} \\
    & 0.5 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{23} \\
    & 0.6 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{25} \\
    & 0.7 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{69} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{54} \\
    & 0.8 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{21} \\
    & 0.9 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{69} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{55} \\\midrule
    \multirow{9}*{\rotatebox[]{-90}{\myheadfont Different beta}} & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{19} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{69} \\
    & 0.2 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{83} \\
    & 0.3 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{35} \\
    & 0.4 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{64} \\
    & 0.5 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{46} \\
    & 0.6 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{12} \\
    & 0.7 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{16} \\
    & 0.8 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{71} \\
    & 0.9 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{38} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know how you managed to make a prison-like table look so good in option 1. This is a very nice answer :)

Comment: @Au101 Thank you. It is why I was so much slower answering!

Comment: @cfr Is there a reason not to nest `tabular`s to build the headings, using lots of `\multicolumn`s instead? Also, I suppose the table will appear better with all-horizontal texts, won't it?

Comment: @Astrinus No, I thought that was a good idea - to use `tabular`s for the heads to reduce the use of `\multicolumn`. Alternatively, you could probably use them for the main part of the table for the same purpose. I am not sure that in this case it would improve things to put the left hand columns horizontally: they will make the table look top-heavy, I think, unless you allow excessive hyphenation. If the data part was wider, it would be different. However, I don't know what is generally recommended typographically on this question.

Comment: I think that "Different\\alpha" and "Different\\beta" (please excuse the little abuse of notation for newlines in cells) or better, a single greek letter, would look nicer.

Comment: @Astrinus A single Greek letter, possibly but it depends on the audience. In any case, it is simple *not* to rotate, so there is no problem if the OP prefers this!

Answer (score 19):

I'll build this up gradually, I'd recommend you compile each snippet with `pdflatex` at each step:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

Now add the `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

add the horizontal and vertical lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    \hline
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

add the column headers

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c@{}|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}
  \hline
  & & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}|c@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{C1}\\ \hline
    P1 & P2 \\ \hline
    0.33 & 0.62\\
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}{c@{}|c@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{C2}\\ \hline
    P1 & P2 \\ \hline
    0.33 & 0.62\\
  \end{tabular}
  \\\hline
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    \hline
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

add the [`multirow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) magic, with `rotatebox` from [`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c@{}@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}
  \hline
  & & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}|c@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{C1}\\ \hline
    P1 & P2 \\ \hline
    0.33 & 0.62\\
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}{c@{}|c@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{C2}\\ \hline
    P1 & P2 \\ \hline
    0.33 & 0.62\\
  \end{tabular}
  \\\hline
  \multirow{6}{1cm}{\rotatebox{90}{different alpha}}  & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    \hline
  \multirow{6}{1cm}{\rotatebox{90}{different beta}}  & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Notes:

- `@{}` removes column space
- you don't have to use a `tabular` for your header, but without it, you might have to do more `multicolumn` work
- I'd enhance this table by using [`siuntix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siuntix) `S` column, and combine it with [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)

Here's a version of how I'd consider presenting it:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccSS}
  \toprule
  & & {\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{C1}\\ \midrule
    P1 & P2 \\ \midrule
    0.33 & 0.62\\
  \end{tabular}}
  &
  {\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{C2}\\ \midrule
    P1 & P2 \\ \midrule
    0.33 & 0.62\\
  \end{tabular}}
  \\\midrule
  \multirow{6}{1cm}{\rotatebox{90}{different alpha}}  & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    \midrule
  \multirow{6}{1cm}{\rotatebox{90}{different beta}}  & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    & 0.1 & 9 & 24 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```